# Port already in use: 9999 error happened on my local CloudConnect

Tags: jvm, port, bind, gooddata

I have reinstalled local CloudConnect (Version: 100.3.0).
After executed any graph on it, I found following error.

java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9999; nested exception is:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

C:\Program Files\Sony\VAIO Care\VCAgent.exe is the program which runs the service binding the port 9999.

Is there any way to let default VM to use another port number to 9999?

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2583832

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some software from Sony is using port 9999 on your computer already. To change the port used by CloudConnect do this:

- go to Eclipse/CloudConnect preferences
- expand "CloudConnect" in the left panel
- click Tracking
- in "Server Host" section change port from 9999 to some other port that is free on your computer

There is also another port used by CloudConnect internally for debugging (default is 4445), you can change it if needed in Logging under in the same menu.